# Выполнение "UB-кода" из-за неправильного предсказания ветвления

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, микроархитектура

Есть код типа такого:

```
if (ptr) ptr->do_something();
```

Из-за неудачного *branch prediction* CPU начал выполнять `ptr->do_something();` с нулевым указателем. Что происходит в таком случае? segfault неявно подавляется? Является ли код, где UB возникает только в случае перестановки операций, UB в целом?

Comment: Оно не может начать _выполняться_. Некая ветвь кода может быть _выбрана_ из памяти и _декодирована_. Но далее будет обнаружено неправильное предсказание и эта ветвь будет отброшена.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov почему только декодирована? Операция должна выполняться как можно дольше, пока не узнали результат сравнения, иначе слабая оптимизация слишком. В данном случае больше не успеет, конечно, но если громоздкое условие какое-нибудь...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вот нашёл подтверждение, что выполняются инструкции,  а не только декодируются - "The branch that is guessed to be the most likely is then fetched and speculatively executed." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

Comment: А зачем такой сложный пример с указателями? просто if(i! =0) return 5/i; нормально же всегда работает, и принципиально от вашего примера ничем не отличается. Никаких исключений не генерируется до того, как предсказание оказалось верным и был запрошен результат вычислений.

Comment: "In Intel 64 and IA-32 processors that implement out-of-order execution microarchitectures, this exception is not generated until an attempt is made to retire the result of executing an invalid instruction; that is, decoding and speculatively attempting to execute an invalid opcode does not generate this exception. Likewise, in the Pentium processor and earlier IA-32 processors, this exception is not generated as the result of prefetching and preliminary decoding of an invalid instruction."

Comment: @xmikex то есть CPU просто устанавливает какой-то условный флаг speculative и если он выставлен, то на все возникающие segfault-ы ждём результата условия и игнорируем, если что?

Comment: их просто не возникнет, так как исполнение спекулятивное реальных обращений к памяти делать не будет.

Comment: @xmikex где можно почитать, как работает спекулятивный режим?

Comment: Совершенно верно, подавляется. Кстати, именно на подобном эффекте реализован [meltdown](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meltdown_(%D1%83%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UB никогда не возникает в результате каких-то нелинейных манипуляций процессора в ходе выполнения кода. UB может содержаться исключительно в исходном коде программы. Если исходный код написан так, что в нем не возникает никакого неопределенного поведения при выполнении на референсной абстрактной машине, то его не должно будет возникать и при исполнении на реальной машине. Собственно в выражении "Неопределенное поведение" идет речь о поведении абстрактной машины, не определенном в стандарте. Задача компилятора заключается в том, чтобы побочные эффекты от выполнения на реальной машине соответствовали таковым при исполнении на абстрактной. А если какие-то неполадки при исполнении программы, не содержащей неопределенного поведения, и случаются, то это будет уже из-за проблем в компиляторе, который не корректно сгенерировал машинный код, или в самом вычислительном устройстве.

Comment: Например, `if (std::rand() == 42) 1 / 0;` содержит UB или нет (в предположении, что при разных запусках `std::rand()` может как выдать `42`, так и не выдать)?

Comment: Конечно содержит. Эта ситуация принципиально отличается от `if (ptr) ptr->do_something();`, где разыменование нулевого указателя не может произойти в принципе.

Comment: Понял, ключевой момент "не может произойти с точки зрения исходного кода", а не "не может произойти реального выполнения"

Comment: `if (std::rand() == 42) 1 / 0;` А если бы `std::rand()` гарантированно никогда не возвращал `42`, то UB или нет?

Comment: @wololo Мне представляется, что основная проблема будет в том, что корректность вычисления константного выражения `1 / 0` вообще не зависит от наличия перед ним условия.

Comment: @vadim Собственно в выражении "Неопределенное поведение" идет речь о поведении абстрактной машины, не определенном в стандарте. А задача компилятора заключается в том, чтобы побочные эффекты от выполнения на реальной машине соответствовали таковым при исполнении на абстрактной.

Answer (score 0):

Если код написан правильно, то ничего не случится. Могу ошибаться, но вроде бы превентивное исполнение вообще не затрагивает код с побочными эффектами.

А вот если неправильно, то есть минимум один случай, в котором превентивное исполнение может привести в сбою. Это использование типа void-функции в качестве коллбэка, который на самом деле должен возвращать int - даже если возвращаемое значение нигде не используется.

Comment: что такое "побочный эффект" в данном контексте?

Comment: @vadim, я не совсем уверен. Скорее всего любая запись в память и вызов прерываний, в том числе page miss.

Answer (score 0):

"Неудачное" ветвление основано на простом правиле, при первом ветвлении, когда в предсказатели нет никакой информации о том какое ветвление наиболее вероятно, он всегда выбирает то которое ведет к коду с наименьшим адресом. Поскольку процедуру `do_something()` ты написал "выше" чем условие `if (ptr)` то `branch prediction` решил сразу перейти к ней еще до того как условие было проверено, если ты перенесешь ее "ниже" по коду, то тогда `branch prediction` при первом проходе будет считать что условие не выполняется, в последующих проходах он будет руководствоваться уже накопленной статистической информацией.

```
UB возникает только в случае перестановки операций, UB в целом?
```

Нет, после того как будет выяснено что это невалидная ветвь, ситуация будет аннулирована.